# undefined method for nil:NilClass refactoring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, null-object-pattern

in transactions, sometimes customers do not have `service_id` because they did not add additional services to cart. problem is, `transactions` index page returns `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` on line

```
<%= transaction.service.name %>
```

Is there any way better than

```
<%= transaction.service.present? ? transaction.service.name : nil %>
```

I found this [NULL OBJECT PATTERN](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/12179019201/design-patterns-in-the-wild-null-object) article. didn't quite understand how it applies on my scenario.

Comment: You tagged the question with `null-object-pattern`? Do you actually know this pattern (because it's a way to go here) or you just picked that tag because it starts with `null-object`?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do this:

```
transaction.service.try(:name)
```

If service is not nil, it will return its name. Or it will return `nil` otherwise.

Comment: by Null Object Pattern I meant http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/12179019201/design-patterns-in-the-wild-null-object

Comment: I didn't quite understood how that applies in my case. hence asking it here.

Comment: Yeah, that's the pattern. You can also watch this: [Null Objects and Falsiness](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/). But I'd go with `try` method in this case.